# JS radio validation from a PHP $_POST form

Tags: php, javascript, validation, forms

I have a form that has a variable number of radio buttons in it:

```
<input id='create' name="post[]" type="radio"  value="<? echo $newphrase; ?>" />
```

I wish to validate it to make sure that at least one button is selected. I have this code:

```
 function valbutton(thisform) {
 myOption = -1;
 for (i=thisform.post.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
 if (thisform.post[i].checked) {
 myOption = i; i = -1;
 }
}
if (myOption == -1) { 
alert("You must select a radio button");
return false;
}
alert("You selected button number " + myOption
+ " which has a value of "
+ thisform.myradiobutton[myOption].value);
thisform.submit(); // this line submits the form after validation
}
```

This works for the validation , but then the $_POST values are not set.
theoretically  this line:

```
for (i=thisform.post.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
if (thisform.post[i].checked) {
```

should read like:

```
for (i=thisform.post[].length-1; i > -1; i--) {
if (thisform.post[][i].checked) {
```

But that obviously doens't work as it errors.

Comment: "I wish to validate it to make sure that at least one button is selected." Really, you should be serving your radio buttons with one explicitly selected in the first place. Then, it shouldn't be possible for the user to get them into a state where none are selected. (Don't rely on browsers to select one by default if none is "checked"; the behaviour in that case is undefined.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. The problem is , its part of a Foreach loop , and there can be 0 radio buttons, but I will investigate your idea further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using Ed Daniels idea of setting "CHECKED" to the radio button. Even though there are a variable number of buttons, it will just 'check' the last one generated, which is good enough in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using the array syntax (name="post[]") for a set of radio buttons. You're only ever going to get one value back at the server, that of the checked radio button.

(For a bunch of checkboxes, where any combination might be checked, it would make sense.)

name="post" in the radio button, and $_POST['post'] in your PHP, should work fine. I suspect that it will also fix your Javascript problem.

Comment: This is part of a loop,  so there can be any number of radio buttons, from 0 to infinity , and any number can be selected.  As you say, it works with just name="post" , but that is no good for me sadly.

Comment: You say that "any number can be selected"; I'm confused as to how you're ever getting more than one radio button to be selected when they share a name (ie they're all in the same set). Checkboxes I could understand, radio buttons no.

Comment: I meant that its a variable number of buttons, including none . Sorry if that wasnt clear.

Answer (score 0):

My recomendation would be to use http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm